# How to create a new user in Tridion 2011 using core services?

Tags: c#, tridion, tridion-2011

I know how to create components, pages, structure group but i got stuck while creating new user using core services of .net?
Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Sorry Chris thats the problem , i cant find any help for this 
and i am newbie so just know how to create component and all stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```cs
public void CreateUser(string userName, string friendlyName, bool makeAdministrator)
{
    var defaultReadOptions = new ReadOptions();

    using (var client = GetCoreServiceClient())
    {
        var user = (UserData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.User, null);
        user.Title = userName;
        user.Description = friendlyName;
        user.Privileges = makeAdministrator ? 1 : 0;
        client.Create(user, defaultReadOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer Peter
I am getting this error now:
ItemType' is an ambiguous reference between 'Tridion.ContentManager.ItemType' and 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ItemType

Comment: Thanks Peter it worked....
Can you tell me how to get the data of a user through its Username:
insted of this
var user = (UserData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.User, null);

Comment: You can't directly load a user by its username -- you have to use the TCM URI. If you really only have the username, you will need to get a list of users first to look up the URI. If you need help with that, please enter a new question as this one is about creating new users.